# C: Many questions about char*

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a bunch of questions about a C program (`arrays-pointers.c`) that has problems:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char * vowels = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};

    printf("sizeof(vowels): %d\n", sizeof(vowels));
}
```

I compile with gcc (`gcc arrays-pointers.c -o arrays-pointers.exe`) and I get warnings (but not outright errors):

```
In function 'main':
warning: initialization of 'char *' from 'int' makes pointer from integer 
    without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  char * vowels = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
                   ^~~
note: (near initialization for 'vowels')
warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
  char * vowels = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
                        ^~~
note: (near initialization for 'vowels')
warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
  char * vowels = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
                             ^~~
note: (near initialization for 'vowels')
warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
  char * vowels = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
                                  ^~~
note: (near initialization for 'vowels')
warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
  char * vowels = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
                                       ^~~
note: (near initialization for 'vowels')
```

In spite of these warnings, gcc produces an executable that consistently outputs:

```
sizeof(vowels): 8
```

My questions are:

- If pointers and arrays are similar, why can't I initialize my array this way?
- What do the warnings mean?
- Why is `sizeof(vowels)` always 8?

Comment: Last question: because you're on a 64-bit system, and asking for the size of a pointer.

Comment: "I have a bunch of questions" Please ask a single one. Otherwise your question is "too broad".

Comment: A pointer is not an array. An array is not a pointer. They are related but not the same thing at all. Warnings mean you likely don't know what you are doing but the compiler is giving you the benefit of the doubt. You can initialise an array with the `{ ... }` syntax, but not a pointer. Sizes of all pointers of the same type are always  the same.

Comment: _"you likely don't know what you are doing"_ - Ha, that's absolutely true =)  I'm making my way through some introductory online lessons and I'm playing around with syntax to try to get an in-depth understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is non trivial to understand because arrays are "strange" in C; they're sort of a "special case" just for historical reasons.

What you need to know is that arrays and pointers are NOT the same thing at all; an array is a block of memory with multiple elements one after another, a pointer is an address of something else.

What creates some confusion is that in many places if you use an array the C language considers instead of the array the pointer to the first element of the array (in legalese the used phrase is "the array decays into a pointer to the first element").

For example

```
int x[] = {1, 2, 3}; // x is an array
foo(x); // you cannot pass an array, a pointer to x[0] is passed instead
```

so your code is is invalid because is like

```
int *x = {1, 2, 3};  // Invalid: {1, 2, 3} is not a valid initializer for a pointer
```

when instead, surprisingly enough, this is valid

```
int x[] = {1, 2, 3};   // An array
int *y = x;            // Fine, it's like writing int *y = &x[0];
```

In the second example the initialization of `y` is valid because in this context there is a rule that says the array automatically "decays" into a pointer to the first element.

This confusion happens because arrays are not objects like the others (for historical reason) and for example assignment of arrays or returning an array from a function or accepting an array parameter is illegal (but, surprisingly, you can assign a structure, pass structures as parameters and return structures from functions... even if the structure contains an array). Fixing this illogical asymmetry now is out of question, as would break most of existing C or C++ programs by changing the meaning of existing code.

C and C++ unfortunately are full of these strange illogical rules, that's why learning C or C++ by experimentation is a bad idea (with C it's a bad idea but may be still doable as its size is small, but with C++ it's a suicide because it's literally a minefield of illogical traps, and a huge one).

To learn C or C++ you need to read the rules.

Don't try to be too smart and guess (guessing doesn't help when the correct answer is illogical).

Comment: _"The array decays into a pointer to the first element"_ - Ah, that's the key to the whole thing.  Now I have something I can google to read more.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize it by creating the array of the chars and then assigning the pointer with its address. This kind of objects are called compound literals.

`char * vowels = (char []){'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};`

Comment: To be useful, that needs some explanation.  Showing an alternative arcane notation with no explanation isn't an awful lot of help.

Answer (score 0):

> If pointers and arrays are similar, why can't I initialize my array
>   this way?

Technically, they aren't exactly similar. You can add manual operations to make pointers act like arrays but they aren't same.

> Why is sizeof(vowels) always 8?

It is the size of the pointer on 64-bit system.

Answer (score 0):

First of all as it has already been said sizeof(int)= 4 bytes in 32-bit architecture or 8 in 64-bit architecture,it has to do with the amount of memory that your system takes to encode an integer.
That been said you have to understand the similarity of pointers and arrays in C. An array is a collection of elements of the same type saved in continuous addresses in memory. We have access to it using a pointer to the first byte of it. So for instance:

int A[5]; is not a pointer just an array, &A or &A[0] (this notation has the same meaning in C) is a pointer to the start (you can call it head if you like) of the array.

A[1] means the second element of the array and it's address (or a pointer to it )is &(A + sizeof(int)) == &(A + 4) in a 32bit machine or software that emulates it (NetBeans for example).

Passing an Array to a function:

First way:

void readTheTheory(int *Arr)
{

}

and call it as readTheTheory(A) or readTheTheory(&A[0])

second way

void readTheTh(int A[])

{

}
and find out how to properly call it on your own